# Getting title of page with php is not UTF-8

Tags: php, html

I used many types of code to get a title of one url address with php, but with all of them, i had problem,

For example,the below code , using DOMDocument :

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents("http://www.farsnews.com/newstext.php?nn=13930431001635"));
// find the title
$titlelist = $doc->getElementsByTagName("title");
if($titlelist->length > 0){
  echo $titlelist->item(0)->nodeValue;
 }
```

The out put of the code , is this :

```
Ã˜Â·Ã˜Â¨Ã™Â‚ Ã˜Â§Ã˜Â¹Ã™Â„Ã˜Â§Ã™Â… Ã™Â…Ã™Â‡Ã˜Â¯Ã›ÂŒ Ã˜ÂªÃ˜Â§Ã˜Â¬ ÃšÂ¯Ã˜Â±Ã˜Â§Ã™Â†Ã¢Â€ÂŒÃ˜ÂªÃ˜Â±Ã›ÂŒÃ™Â† Ã˜Â¨Ã˜Â§Ã˜Â²Ã›ÂŒÃšÂ©Ã™Â† Ã™ÂÃ™ÂˆÃ˜ÂªÃ˜Â¨Ã˜Â§Ã™Â„ Ã˜Â§Ã›ÂŒÃ˜Â±Ã˜Â§Ã™Â† Ã™Â…Ã˜Â¹Ã˜Â±Ã™ÂÃ›ÂŒ Ã˜Â´Ã˜Â¯
```

But the title of that page is this :

```
طبق اعلام مهدی تاج گران‌ترین بازیکن فوتبال ایران معرفی شد
```

So, the problem is with encoding of the string . May be the problem is just with this site !
But how ti fix this ? And echo out the correct title ?

- edit:

i have tested this meta :

```
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

But no results.

Comment: your code works for me

Comment: @Fabricator You mean you get title without problem? So where is my problem ?

Comment: did you save the php script that outputs the title to UTF8 encoding as well?

Comment: @PatrickEvans yes i have saved it. + I tested the code is some Sites like phpfiddle , there was no problem there. just i see error !

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if you php internal encoding handle UTF-8 correctly?

```
<?php 
var_dump(mb_internal_encoding()); 
?>
```